# Microsoft Graph API - sendMail API error - "The requested user 'foobar@private.com' is invalid."

Tags: r, json, http, post, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to understand how to send mail using Microsoft Graph sendMail API after creating an Azure AD app with 'Application permissions' for Microsoft Graph 'Mail.Send' and 'User.Read'. I am successfully using the client_id, tenant_id and client_secret to obtain an apparently valid token and subsequently submitting a POST to the api like this (R code):

```r
from_address <- "foobar@private.com"
    
url <- paste0("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/", from_address, "/sendMail")
resp <- POST(url,
             add_headers(.headers = c(content_type = "application/json",
                                      Authorization = paste("Bearer", token))),
             body = upload_file("mail.json"))
```

The content of "mail.json" is:

```json
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "someone@somewhere.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, I get this 404 response:

```json
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorInvalidUser\",\"message\":\"The requested user 'foobar@private.com' is invalid.\"}}"
```

The Microsoft account I am using is private and the address represented above with foobar@private.com is the main 'signin' mail address for the account. I'm not sure if this user needs some special permissions or if it has to be a "corporate account". The plan is to use this within a corporate Microsoft account to send mails but I am currently testing with a private account to determine how it works.

Comment: Btw, I see you're an R user. You could try using my [Microsoft365R](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R) package, which now has Outlook support in the dev version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of how to `POST` to the Microsoft Graph SendMail api are correct in the question. The problem was only in the configuration of the application in Microsoft Azure portal Active directory. The administrator of the `tenant` created an app with two permissions with 'Admin consent'. The first is a Delegated permission, `Microsoft Graph: 'Sign in and read user profile'` the second is an Application permission, `Microsoft Graph: 'Send mail as any user'`. The first is used to get a token that is valid for 1 hour and the second is used in the code you see in the question to send the mail itself with the aquired token. I have been told that there is a restriction in place that only makes it possible to send mail from one specific 'no-reply' address at the organization so you can't use the api to impersonate someone else. It is not clear to me how that restriction works just that is does.

Answer (score 2):

The [syntax for the call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail
```

The tricky part is, as far as I can tell, personal Microsoft accounts don't have a userPrincipalName. Your "foobar@private.com" is an email address, but it isn't used as an identifier within Azure Active Directory or Graph.

Instead, you have to use your ID. You can get this with

```
GET /me
```

and the ID is the `id` field in the response.

Note that you may run into a separate problem with using an email address in the call, when it comes to work & school accounts. Commonly, people will have an address like "firstname.lastname@company.com", but this is only an alias for convenience; their userPrincipalName might be something more cryptic like "id123456@companytenantname.com". For this reason, it's best to stick to IDs throughout.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be part of the problem solved. However, I am now getting a different 404 response: "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI\",\"message\":\"REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.\"}}" which I understand may be related to the type of microsoft account but the send mail works in graph explorer with this account so perhaps I am missing something else on the configuration in the Azure web interface. Do you have any tips for this problem?

Comment: Did you sign up for a free Outlook account? https://outlook.com But as mentioned in my other comment, you could use Microsoft365R which has Outlook support coming in the next release

Comment: Yes, its a free account for testing but the purpose is to develop a process that will be used in a "work & school account". We are currently testing your R package to see if we can get it to work from that.

Comment: What I mean is, to get email working with a personal account, you still have to sign up for the Outlook service

Comment: OK, I'm confused about these Microsoft accounts/services. How can I add outlook service to an account? Or it is better to just use the work/school account and ask the administrator to add the permissions required so we can test within that account?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/microsoft-365/outlook/email-and-calendar-software-microsoft-outlook How are you talking to Graph? You should be able to reuse the app ID with Microsoft365R

Comment: We are talking to graph with the httr package in R. We will try to use this same appID via Microsoft365R. I'm convinced we'll eventually get it to work; when we do I'll come back here and update this thread with what our problem was and how we fixed it.